# Chain pairs in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, for example, `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I need to get pairs of it (using C# LINQ):

`(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)`

Strangely, I can't solve this simple task, though I tried **SelectMany** with **Skip(i + 1)**, which gives me all possible pairs, that I basically don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with Linq [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) method:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var pairs = numbers.Zip(numbers.Skip(1));

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"First: {pair.First}, Second: {pair.Second}");
}
```

Output:

```
First: 1, Second: 2
First: 2, Second: 3
First: 3, Second: 4
First: 4, Second: 5
```

Running example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HZuDdR

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var pairs = list.Take(list.Count() - 1).Select((z, index) => new
        {
            a = z, b = list[index + 1]
        }).ToList();
        pairs.ForEach(p => Console.Write("(" + p.a + "," + p.b + ") "));
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6oXQwC

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `ToList` here, and always avoid using `List.ForEach` when there is no real benefit to using a standard `foreach` loop. (see [here](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) for why)

Comment: True, and your solution with zip is also much cleaner.

Comment: Zip solution is cleaner indeed, but it doesn't work on some c# versions for some reason